# Docker can't reach and be reached to and from outside

Tags: linux, docker

I have deployed my `.NET` and `Angular` applications through docker on our `Linux machine`. As soon as `.NET` app starts, it gets an error as it cannot connect to `database`

```
 ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to x.x.x.x:xxxx
 ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|191_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at emetry.health.infrastructure.Repositories.Alerts.NotificationsRepository.GetNotifications(NotificationFilter filter) in /src/src/emetry.health.infrastructure/Repositories/Alerts/NotificationsRepository.cs:line 14
   at emetry.health.application.Services.AlertReadingService.DoWork(Object state) in /src/src/emetry.health.application/Services/AlertReadingService.cs:line 50
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
 ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to x.x.x.x:xxxx
 ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|191_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at emetry.health.infrastructure.Repositories.Shopping.UserSubscriptionRepository.GetAllWithDetailsAsync(UserSubscriptionFilter filter) in /src/src/emetry.health.infrastructure/Repositories/Shopping/UserSubscriptionRepository.cs:line 16
   at emetry.health.application.Services.RecurringPaymentService.DoWork(Object state) in /src/src/emetry.health.application/Services/RecurringPaymentService.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
```

`Angular` applications are started but they are not reachable from outside

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                   NAMES
77c1d3fb15a4   xxxxxxxxx   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   17 hours ago   Up 23 minutes   0.0.0.0:5009->80/tcp, :::5009->80/tcp   x-2
f0f0d5db8255   xxxxxxxxx   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   17 hours ago   Up 23 minutes   0.0.0.0:5008->80/tcp, :::5008->80/tcp   x-1
```

As I try to reach them from browser I get this error code

[image: error]

Everything was working fine with several different deploys of the same applications and at some point it starts to fail. It seems that `docker` is isolated and cannot communicate with outside. **How could I solve this problem?**

Before the problem appeared, `docker containers` were running fine and it got exited 6 days ago for some reason. Ports were still listening and applications were working. Then I tried to deploy a new version and it failed because ports were already bound. After restarting docker service problem appeared.

Dockerfiles:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/app.api/NuGet.Config", "src/app.api/"]
COPY ["src/NuGet.Config", "src/"]
COPY ["NuGet.Config", "."]
COPY ["src/app.api/app.api.csproj", "src/app.api/"]
COPY ["src/app.infrastructure/app.infrastructure.csproj", "src/app.infrastructure/"]
COPY ["src/app.domain/app.domain.csproj", "src/app.domain/"]
COPY ["src/app.application/app.application.csproj", "src/app.application/"]
COPY ["src/app.shared/app.shared.csproj", "src/app.shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/app.api/app.api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/app.api"
RUN dotnet build "app.api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "app.api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.api.dll"]
```

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:16-alpine as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
ARG COMMAND
RUN echo ${COMMAND}
RUN npm run ${COMMAND}
# Stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
^version: '3.7'

services:
  API:
    image: $DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH/api:$API_VERSION
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: $ENVIRONMENT
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      mode: replicated
      endpoint_mode: vip
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 1
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        order: stop-first
        failure_action: rollback
    ports: [ $API_PORT ]
  UI:
    image: $DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH/ui:$UI_VERSION
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      mode: replicated
      endpoint_mode: vip
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        order: stop-first
        failure_action: rollback
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 100M
    ports: [ $UI_PORT ]
  UI_ADMIN:
    image: $DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH/ui_admin:$UI_ADMIN_VERSION
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      mode: replicated
      endpoint_mode: vip
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        order: stop-first
        failure_action: rollback
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 100M
    ports: [ $UI_ADMIN_PORT ]
```

Comment: please show your `Dockerfile`

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko attached

Comment: Can you tell how you run those containers?

Comment: @Philippe everything is managed through `teamcity`, but basically `docker-compose -p app up -d` command is ran

Comment: Then you can post docker-compose.yml

Comment: @Philippe attached

Comment: what and where is `database`?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko it is not important what and where is the database as it is not only the connection to database problem, but generally not reaching docker container from the outside and vice-versa

Comment: where is the database hosted? is it hosted on host machine, where docker containers are running ?